# How to notify React to update page from Ruby on Rails backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, web

I need to update React page automatically (without page refresh) when Ruby on Rails backend api sends some kind of notification.

I was thinking about websockets but I'm interested in best way to achieve page update probably using some plugin dedicated to websockets. It would be one way notification (only backend api -react, not other way).

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets would be the ideal way to handle this because it's specifically made for the situation where you want the BE to send some info the client side in an async fashion.

You can use the `actioncable` package that rails provides for react. Just run `npm install actioncable --save` and then you can set it up so that:

1. On component `mount` it creates a consumer subscription to the channel such as:

```js
import { createConsumer, disconnect } from 'actioncable';

const cableConsumer = createConsumer(`ws://${...url}/cable?token=${token};

// And on unmount you can just disconnect this by simply doing

cableConsumer.disconnect();

// Additionally once you cableConsumer you can setup a listener such as:

cableConsumer.subscriptions.create(
   { channel: 'SomeChannel' },   // channel name on rails side will be some_channel
   { received: this.handleUpdate }
);

// your handleUpdate can handle the actual state update to display the updated value.
```

For the token, if you are concerned about security one flow you can follow is:

1. On user login create a token for user. Immediately use token to create `cableConsumer`.
2. As part of your `createConsumer` request you can `deprecate` the token so it can't be used again to open another channel.